# mActivity from Fragment.onAttach() not retained

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java

I have setup a Observable/Subscriber with RxJava. The Observable is created in MainActivity. The Subscriber is a  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`called MyFragment. The Observable gets data from RESTful service and stores the data in a SQLite db on the device. This works. When its work is done, which takes 4 or 5 seconds such that MyFragment has already processed `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` etc., the subscriber, MyFragment, is notified via its implemented `onNext()` method (this works) and is then reads data from the SQLite db (this also works) and is the supposed to populate a view (this does not work).

The problem is that my class member mActivity is null in the method `loadDataFromSQLite()`. The lesson I think I am learning is that nothing with a `Fragment` can be done outside of methods in the Fragment class (from `onAttach()` to `onDestroy()`)

That being the case, how do I do this?

See below for code snippets:

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Observer<String> { 

    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onNext(String string) {
        loadDataFromSQLite();

    }

    public void loadDataFromSQLite() {
        <get data from SQLite>
        // now want to populate view
        // mActivity is null
        mTableLayout = (TableLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_table_layout);
    }
}
```

fragment_table_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_table_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!--  fill in data in MyFragment.java -->
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

I should add the I also tried calling `getActivity()` in place of `mActivity`, but it returns null

Comment: try using `getActivity` method instead of processing on mActivity attribute

Comment: are you sure that you have attached the fragment to your activity , because `getActiviy` returns null only if fragment is not attached to any activity

Comment: `onAttach` is definitely being called and `mActivity` is assigned a valid value at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly this line is a problem:

```
mTableLayout = (TableLayout) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_table_layout);
```

This means you are casting a view that doesn't belong to that Fragment, in that Fragment. All view plumbing of a Fragment (including finding that TableLayout) should be done in `Fragment.onCreateView`. Later you can use their references elsewhere in the Fragment, like this:

```
TableLayout mTableLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ...) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
   mTableLayout = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_table_layout);
   ...
   return view; 
}
```

Another thing is that you cannot configure one of two processes to update the other one simply because you expect it to take longer. This is unreliable and this is what you do by calling a REST API to update a fragment that you're not sure has been created. You can force the creation of a Fragment by invoking `FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()` but you still need to prepare for the case when the fragment is already gone when REST response arrives.

It is also important to note that keeping a reference to an Activity is a bad idea. You should always use `getActivity` in a Fragment. If at any point it returns null then it means the Activity the Fragment is anchored to is not yet created or already destroyed.

Comment: Ok, I've removed mActivity and now use `getActivity()` instead. On the callbacks, e.g. `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()`, `getActivity()` returns a value. Within loadDataFromSQLite(), however, it returns null. You say that this means that the Activity that the Fragment is anchored to
is not yet created or has been destroyed, but I don't see how that's possible. The fragment is still being displayed on the device.

Comment: Well you may have more than one problem and I expanded my answer. I am assuming you are calling a REST and creating a fragment at the same time. If so, one thing you can do is create Fragment first using `executePendingTransactions` then call your REST. In a bigger picture, I'd suggest doing both REST and database in Activity and only send final processed data to Fragment using Event Bus. I feel you use non-singleton SQLiteOpenHelper which requires a Context. And this shouldn't be supplied with `Fragment.getActivity` which may return null.

Comment: (sorry for the delay, gone last week) ... So I now use `executePendingTransactions`to create the fragment in `MainActivity.onStart()`. Do I need to check if this transaction gets completed (if so, how?) or am I guaranteed that it will complete quickly?

Comment: Without `executePendingTransactions` fragment transaction including creation is done asynchronously. So if you use it, any subsequent methods will be executed after your fragment creation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem because you're presuming that `onNext` will be called after `onAttach`, but as you've noticed, that's not necessarily the case. I would say you have two options:

1. subscribe to the observable in the `onAttach` and not before, that way you're making sure that the `onNext` will be called after;
2. in `onNext` check if the activity is null and if it is, save the data for later. then in `onAttach` check if you have the data and if yes, visualize it. that way you will be able to save some time by loading the data concurrently with initialization of the fragment, but you will have to have a method that will be called twice with inside something like `if (getActivity != null && mData != null) { ... }`.

So, the first one is more elegant, but the second might be more efficient.

PS. obviously, all findViewById should be done in `onCreateView()`.