# IllegalArgumentException:No view found for id

Tags: android, android-layout

I get the following exception:
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

No view found for id 0x7f04001a (com.whatever:layout/fragment_main)*

Looking at similar questions on SO:

One answer suggests using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.
This is not an option since `MainActivity` is not a `Fragment`.

Another answer suggests that fragment_main is not a child of activity_main, but I think I have that setup in activity_main.xml with `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main`

Another suggests that `setContent()` has not been called, but I have that in `onCreate()`

What am I missing?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // create fragment immediately
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.layout.fragment_main, new MainActivityFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        boolean wereThereWereAnyPendingTransactions = fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

MainActivityFragment.java

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment  implements Observer<String> {
        public MainActivityFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.whatever.MainActivityFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_main_table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/fragment_main_xml"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The answer with respect to code:
actvity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:id="@+id/activity_frame_layout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
  ...
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_frame_layout, new MainActivityFragment());
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you embed a `Fragment` inside of an `Activity` XML layout, you do not create it dynamically.  The system does it for you.  So there is no need to create the transaction and commit it, the `Fragment` will be created and added when you called `setContentView()`.

Note that the `tools:layout=` line does not do anything at runtime.  It is strictly for the tools to better link layouts and components together.

Comment: I need to create the Fragment immediately because I am then going to load data from a RESTful service. [see here for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464719/mactivity-from-fragment-onattach-not-retained) if you want. 
How do I set this up?

Comment: The `Fragment` is already being created for you, if done statically like this.  You can take this approach, but remember that you will not be able to use `FragmentTransaction` to replace or remove it.  If you need the `Fragment` to be dynamically added/removed/replaced, then you will use `FragmentTransaction` appropriately and your `activity_main.xml` will not declare the `<fragment>`, but instead a `View` to use as a container of the `Fragment`, such as a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: I've changed activity_main.xml to a FrameLayout, but the error still occurs. What else do I need to do?

Comment: If you've changed `activity_main.xml` to have a `FrameLayout`, change the first argument of `fragmentTransaction.add()` to be the ID of the `FrameLayout`, not `R.layout.activity_main`.